# Strange behavior of a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, behavior

I'm creating an application (**TabBar based**) and I'm adding in the **first view** an **`UINavigationController`** with a **`UITableViewController`** as its rootViewController.

In the documentation I read that a `TableView` owned by a `UITableViewController`, if not stated differently, has as `delegate` and `dataSource` his own tableViewController.

The problem is that the methods of the two protocols (`UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`) are never called (figured out using `NSLog()`).

I know I've made an error at some point, can't understand where.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you question correctly but here's a rough guess.

Have you set your datasource and delegate for your UITableView like somewhere in your viewDidLoad method?

Like say you got something declared like this:

```
@interface MyViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
    UITableView *myTableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *myTableView;

@end
```

In your viewDidLoad method in the implementation file, you should have something similar like:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    [myTableView setDelegate:self]; //this view controller (MyViewController) will be the delegate
    [myTableView setDataSource:self]; // data will come from this view controller itself

    ...

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Is that what you were after?

Comment: I created a separated class (UITableViewController subclass) and imported it in the firstViewController of the tabBarController.
There I created an instance of the class and pushed it in a navigation controller.
When the tableView is supposed to appear the delegate's methods are not called (--> empty table view).

Comment: Are you able upload your project somewhere I can try and debug?